# starting android service using explicit vs implicit intent

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, implicit, explicit

According to the standard Android documentation, the prefered way to start a service (started service that is) is to use an explicit intent like this:

```
// Using explicit intent:
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
// or:
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
startService(serviceIntent);
```

You can also start/stop a service using an implicit intent with an action string specified in the manifest, like this:

```
// Using implicit intent:
static final String serviceAction = "com.example.my.app.services.MYSERVICE";
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(serviceAction);
startService(serviceIntent);

// AndroidManifest.xml:
<service android:name="com.example.my.app.services.MyService"
   android:exported="false" android:process=":services" >
   <intent-filter>
      <!-- Start/Stop service -->
      <action android:name="com.example.my.app.services.MYSERVICE" />
   </intent-filter>
</service>
```

When the service is used only locally (third party applications are not allowed to start or bind to it), the documentation says that you should not include an **intent-filter** in the manifest **service** tag and you should set the **exported** tag to false.

Note: the activities and services run in separate processes (:application and :services processes). The communication between activity and service is done by implementing AIDL interfaces (this is done because only AIDL remote interfacing allows me to do multi-threading within the service that needs to handle IPC simultanously, not only between activities but mostly between services running within the :services process).

My questions are:

Q1: When the activities and services I use in my app are run in two different processes, do I need to use implicit intents over explicit intents to start and stop the services?

Q2: When the :application process is gone (destroyed, not in memory anymore) and the :services process is running in the background, how do I connect again from a new :application process to the already running :services process? Somehow I need to get a reference to the :services process again so that I can stop the running service inside that process. This cannot be done using AIDL afaik.

The problem is that Android can and will destroy the :application process easily when out of resources, and that is fine by me as long as the :services process keeps running.
(Yes, I know about influencing the process by setting the service as a foreground service, etc. I too can read manuals ;)  but that is not my problem).

I cannot find any information or answers related to my questions when the activities and services are in separated processes and use AIDL, AND when the :application process needs to "find" the :services process again after it has been killed by Android or when the user enters the app again (after he/she left the app before).

Any expert-level advise is welcome.

Comment: "Note: the activities and services run in separate processes (:application and :services processes)" -- please just get rid of that. It is not needed, makes your app more complex, wastes RAM, wastes CPU/battery, etc.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for the advise, I am considering it. But what about the questions, these are not yet addressed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A1 : Even though your activity and service run in different processes they still belong to same Application. You can still use explicit intent, I don't see any specific advantage of using implicit intent here (let me know if find any :) )

A2 : let me list down few facts here

- Life cycle of "Started" service (rather than "Bind"ed service) is independent of the life cycle of Activity which has started this service. This is true irrespective whether both are running in the same process or not.
- Only one instance of Service will be alive at any point of time. when your activity calls startService() , service instance will be created if it is not already running (in this case you service will receive onCreate() callback as well). But if Service is already running, Framework would simply call onStartCommand() callback on already running process(No onCreate() callback in this case). Again all this is true irrespective of activity and service are running on same process or different processes.

Now to answer your question, if you service is still running (because of startService() call by previous activity), then bindService()/startService() will make sure to connect to existing service.

Hope this is of some help to you. Let me know if you have any other specific questions.

Comment: Hi, just to answer to your "let me know if find any". When you use a implicit intent you are using a explicit implementation of a service (or... an interface really). This means that you cannot chose your own implementation (you should change your code to do that).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use an implicit intent to start a service or activity in a separate process; however, using a separate process for an Activity is a rare scenario. Using a separate process for a Service is more common, but nevertheless I'd like to know what the use case is.

If your application process is destroyed and then restarted, you'd use startService to reconnect to the Service. If the Service is running, you connect to it, otherwise the Service is restarted. If you then want to kill the Service, you can kill it, or you can run stopService() from your main app.

What is the service doing?