# What is the use of intent-filter in the manifest for a service?

Tags: android, intentfilter

I am in a train and suddenly thought of something.

If I am allowed to declare my service as below:

```
<service
    android:name=".service.MyService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="INTENT_SAMPLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

I know that doing below will result to `IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit` error.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("INTENT_SAMPLE");
intent.setType("text/plain");
startService(intent);
```

Then, what is the use of `intent-filter` in this case, if there is any?

Comment: Only have an <intent-filter> on a component when you want third-party apps to communicate with that component. You seem to have fallen into the trap of assuming that you need an <intent-filter> for everything -- in reality, you infrequently need an <intent-filter>. An explicit Intent is when you designate the component to talk to in the Intent itself, usually using the constructor that takes a Java Class object as the second parameter. That, rather than implicit Intents and <intent-filter>s, are what you should use for components local to your app

Comment: There used to be.  That exception is relatively new, in the history of Android.  Security issues forced the Android designers to surgically remove the original functionality.  You are looking at the scar left from that surgery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answers, the intent filter helps your service classify the type of action to execute. So for example, you can try starting the service like below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
intent.setAction("INTENT_SAMPLE");
startService(intent);
```

Then in `MyService` class, check for the action like so:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if("INTENT_SAMPLE".equals(intent.getAction())) {
        // do INTENT_SAMPLE action here
    }
    else {
        // do non INTENT_SAMPLE action here
    }
}
```

Since https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#Types does not recommend intent filters for services, drop the action from manifest. To achieve the same result as above, simply add an extra to your intent like so:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
intent.putExtra("INTENT_SAMPLE", true);
startService(intent);
```

Then in `MyService` class, check for the action like so:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if(intent.getBooleanExtra("INTENT_SAMPLE", false)) {
        // do INTENT_SAMPLE action here
    }
    else {
        // do non INTENT_SAMPLE action here
    }
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

```
   try this code....
   <code>
    //MainActivity.class
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context,MyService.class);
    serviceIntent.setAction("INTENT_SAMPLE");
    startService(serviceIntent);

  // Myservice.class
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
  {
      string action=intent.getAction();
      if(action.equals("your action"))
      {...}
  }
  </code>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a service to perform different actions, then declaring an intent filter will help your service match against different actions you want to perform.

It allows you to use the same service for different actions, instead of creating two separate services for example.

However, having intent filters declared for a service is not regarded as a good practice, and this is what the docs had to say:

> Caution: To ensure your app is secure, always use an explicit intent
>   when starting a Service and do not declare intent filters for your
>   services. Using an implicit intent to start a service is a security
>   hazard because you cannot be certain what service will respond to the
>   intent and the user cannot see which service starts.

I found many answers on SO only regarding same:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/17940558/1318946
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/47329692/1318946
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/40059566/1318946
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4063426/1318946
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/20096953/1318946

I hope it will clear to you.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

the definition for intent is 
An Intent is a simple message object that is used to communicate between android components such as activities, content providers, broadcast receivers and services. Intents are also used to transfer data between activities.

and there are two types of intents
Implicit Intent
Explicit Intent

Implicit intent is use two define the action that you want to perform for different activities

Explicit Intent is used for launch a specific app component, such as a particular activity or service in your app

that's why you have to defined the intent in intent-filter in manifest so the system will know which type of intent is it

you can refers this links for further and detailed understanding of the topic :-
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element